# Restrict access of (an) individual comment(s) to (a) certain user(s)

Tags: users, comments, blocks

So, there are a lot of modules (and *Drupal-Answers* posts discussing them) to restrict access of certain **node** types / individual **nodes** to individual users, and it can be a pretty hard task to know which 1 might be best, according to your needs.

Now, something else: is there a possibility to restrict access of individual **comments** to individual users?

Would this be possible with the module [Block Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access)? (Since they state to be able to change:)

> permissions at the individual block level

Perhaps, if there would be a module; restricting **node** access to individual users; that can also restrict access to **comments**, then perhaps the choice of an access-restriction-module could be easier for people interested in this feature.

Comment: How about creating a new role and assigning it for individuals for whom you want to restrict access?

Comment: @Aparna - *Thanks for your comment.* Is this possible for individual comments? Do you mean, using the module [Block Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access)?